# Android - Download title and description from a website

Tags: android, html, http

I am currently using HttpClient from Android to get the full contents of website in html and then parsing the data to get Title and Description. Problem is some websites don't have description (Eg: Google) and there are some sites which contain huge amount of data (Eg: yahoo).

Is it required to download the entire page to get title and description ?

Comment: This seems more like an http/html question than an Android question. You might get better results if you change the tag(s) accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to download entire webpage to get title and description.